# Coming up with a linear time solution for the following problem

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory

There are n packages, numbered 1 to n. A set K of pairs (i, j) defines a list of dependencies such that package j cannot be installed without installing package i.

Come up with a linear time algorithm that takes a list K, and produces the list of all packages that are necessary to install package 1.

Here is my attempt:

```
function algortihm(n,K)
    radix sort K(i,j) on key j
    dependencies <- arr size n   //declare array           
    currPackage <- 1
    tempArr <- K
    function func(currPackage, K) 
        dependencies.append(currPackage)
        count <- -1
        for (i,j) in K:
            if j not in dependencies:
                count <- count + 1
                if j == currPackage:
                    tempArr.remove(count)
                    func(i, tempArr)
                endif
            endif
            if j > currPackage:
                break
            endif
        endfor
    endfunction
    return dependencies
endfunction
```

Using this input K = (1, 2) (3, 2) (3, 4) (4, 1) (5, 1) (5, 4) (6, 8) (8, 3) (7, 6)

Radix sort has complexity O(n) and will reduce the number of times the list is iterated through because if we sort by dependencies (key j) then we know that once j exceeds the size of the package we know there are no more dependency listings and the for loop can be broken out of.

List after sorting: (4, 1) (5, 1) (1, 2) (3, 2) (8, 3) (3, 4) (5, 4) (7, 6) (6, 8)

Furthermore, every time a dependency is found, it is removed from a temporary array, which is then passed recursively into the function.
It also ensures that a call or iteration/comparison isn’t made if the dependency is already recorded.

This works out to about 37 comparisons being made, but I know it is not linear time. I just can't spot what would be faster than what I've got it to already, it is difficult to analyse the complexity of the algorithm I have come up with but I reckon it is O(n^2/b)

Comment: This is in essence topological sorting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think so. Topological sort would help you identify an order in which all packages can be installed without violating any dependency but will not help you identify the minimal set of packages needed to be installed before installing a specific package

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: well you simply sort in reverse: you take that package as root, and then you "schedule backwards" the depaendecheduled.

Comment: I have to agree with @WillemVanOnsem. Basically, you need to think of your problem not as a sorting per se but, a topological sorting. You consider the packages as nodes and the directed edges in the graph represent the dependency relation between them. If you do that, a topological sort gives you the ordered list of package dependencies; traversing in reverse gives you the correct installation order. A plus, you can detect circular dependencies!

Comment: @JorgeLopez please take a look at the answer I have provided below. It suggest just what you describe. Still this is not topological sort, it is graph walk instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sort is not appropriate for this problem. You would be able to sort all the nodes but identifying the minimal set of packages needed to be installed before a given package will be hard.

A better approach is to consider the dependencies as edges in a graph and represent them in reverse direction. That is if there is a dependency `(i, j)` (meaning `i` should be installed before `j`), add an edge from `j` to `i` in your graph. Now having defined this graph, the list of packages that need to be installed before package `x` are exactly those packages that are reachable from `x` in the thus defined graph. To find which are those nodes you can use and graph search algorithm e.g. breadth first search or depth first search.

Comment: Well, you assume there are no circular dependencies in the packages. However, from the description of the original question it says nothing. Assume the original problem gets as input P={1,2,3,4,5}, D={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,3)}. You create your graph from this input and your depth first search goes to an infinite loop. Certainly, if you can assume there are no such dependencies then your proposed solution is nice cuz an Inorder traversal will give the package installation order.

Comment: @JorgeLopez are you serious? DFS going into infinite cycle if there is a circular dependency? Both BFS and DFS work just fine on any graph not just on tree or DAG

Comment: thanks, hadn't considered that rather perceptive approach

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: DFS indeed goes in an infinite loop if it has no cycle detection mechanism, as is written on Wikipedia "Performing the same search without remembering previously visited nodes results in visiting nodes in the order A, B, D, F, E, A, B, D, F, E, etc. forever, caught in the A, B, D, F, E cycle and never reaching C or G.". If one does not remember visited edges, then graph walking can result in exponential behavior as well, since imagine that `A` depends on `B` and `C`, and `B` and `C` depend on `D`, and `D` depends on `E` and `F` and so on, it doubles every second generation.

Comment: I am aware that you need to keep track of the visited nodes and that is what is typically meant by DFS unless indicated otherwise. You can also note that the example implementations on the same wikipedia article do that(although I don't consider wikipedia to be the best source of truth for algorithms)